# docker-machine virtualbox - how to access machine over lan

Tags: docker, debian, virtualbox, docker-machine

I created virtual machine (dock): `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dock`

selected env: `docker-machine env dock`, `eval $(docker-machine env dock)`

applied my compose: `docker-compose up`

Machine is acceesible but only from host. I wanted to make it accesible from lan network. ex( from other pc in the same network where host is by putting host ip and port in http)

**Host OS: debian 10.** 
**Docker container : nginx**

Possible?